# Using regex to match URL strings with exactly one forward slash in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So I'm trying to match a set of URL strings that have only one forward slash. This would indicate that they are all from the homepage regardless of whether or not any variables are passed in the URL.

So for example `/` would match, `/?=somevar` would match, but `/page/` would not.

I tried to do `[^\/]*\/[^\/]*` and `\/{1}` but they're both neither here nor there. What can I do to match strings with only one use of a character?

Comment: You need `^[^/]*/[^/]*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^/[^/]*$
```

Its very permissive and allows any character in the URL, so you may want to tighten it up to specify only valid URL characters. For example:

```
^/[a-zA-Z0-9?&=]*$
```